# Excel-vba proteger hojas con contraseña

Tags: excel, vba

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que cada vez que quiera abrir una hoja me pida una contraseña? Lo que quiero es que cada vez que cambie de hoja dentro de un libro, me pida contraseña (cada hoja la suya).

He probado este código pero no funciona:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
Dim MySheets As String, Response As String
MySheet = "Sheet1"
If ActiveSheet.Name = inicio Then
ActiveSheet.Visible = False
Response = InputBox("Enter password to view sheet")
    If Response = "abc" Then
        Sheets(MySheet).Visible = True
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Sheets(MySheet).Select
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End If
Sheets(MySheet).Visible = True
End Sub
```

El nombre de la hoja que estoy probando es "INICIO" y la contraseña "abc".

¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: tu código tiene varios fallos ahora mismo. Para empezar, no has definido la variable `inicio`. además, haces `Dim MySheets` pero luego usas `MySheet = "Sheet1"`. ¿Y la S final?. También, ten cuidado con el `ActiveSheet.Visible = False` porque cuando lo ejecutas, Excel vuelve a la hoja donde estabas, activando de nuevo el evento. Crearás un bucle que hará invisibles todas las hojas hasta que dé fallo porque un libro debe tener al menos 1 hoja activa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

este código no es exactamente lo que quieres, pero podría servirte para empezar. Lo que hecho ha sido, en vez de ocultar hojas, simplemente bloquear el cambio de hojas. Es decir, un usuario quiere cambiar de hoja, se le pide contraseña, y si es errónea, se queda en la hoja en la que está.

He optado por esta opción porque estar ocultando y mostrando hojas es complicar el código mucho, pero si lo necesitas, se podría hacer. Pero al menos con mi código creo que puede servirte como punto de partida :)

```
Public HojaActual As Worksheet


Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Set HojaActual = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

Dim Response As String

Response = InputBox("Enter password to view sheet")

If Response = "abc" Then
    'el password es correcto. No hacemos nada, pero actualizamos la variable pública
    Set HojaActual = Nothing
    Set HojaActual = Sh
Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    MsgBox "Wrong password", vbCritical, "ACCESS DENIED!"
    HojaActual.Activate
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: muchas gracias, creo que esta forma es mejor. Esto lo pongo en ThisWorkbook? Y cómo puedo aplicar este código a distintas hojas? Me refiero, cada hoja debe tener una contraseña. Lo siento, es que soy nuevo en esto y me urge un poco

Comment: Esto lo tienes que pegar en el Workbook, sí. En VBA puedes tener código en 3 sitios (objetos). En una hoja, y solo se activará con eventos de la hoja; en un libro, y se activa con los eventos del libro (así está mi código), y en un módulo (o módulo de clase). Es una explicación un poco burda, pero por simplificarlo. Mi código es del objeto Workbook. Se ejecutará siempre que cambies de hoja. Si quieres añadir contraseñas específicas para cada hoja, puedes usar un `Select Case....End Select` para exigir la correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Al final he usado este código:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

    Dim mySheet As String: mySheet = "Sheet1"
    Dim response As String

    If Sh.Name = mySheet Then
        response = InputBox("Enter password to view sheet")
        Sh.Visible = CBool(response = "abc")
    End If

    End Sub
```